# Prism.Unity.Forms 8.1 container.resolve stoped working after upgrade from version 7.2

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, unity-container

I'm not a developer, but I managed to make an Xamarin.forms android app with prism 7.2, but recently I needed to add more features to the app and updated all NuGet packages, which updated Prism to version 8.

After the upgrade when I try to resolve on a tabbedpage:

```
_unityContainer.Resolve<IMyTabbedPageSelectedTab>().SetSelectedTab(0);
```

I get the following Unity.ResolutionFailedException: 'Resolution failed with error: No public constructor is available for type XXX.Interfaces.IMyTabbedPageSelectedTab.'

My interface is:

```
public interface IMyTabbedPageSelectedTab
{
    int SelectedTab { get; set; }
    void SetSelectedTab(int tabIndex);
}
```

My MainPageViewModel:

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMyTabbedPageSelectedTab
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

    private int _selectedTab;
    public int SelectedTab
    {
        get { return _selectedTab; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedTab, value);
            Title = $"My Tabbed Page - Tab [{SelectedTab + 1}]";
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IUnityContainer unityContainer): base(navigationService)
    {
        Title = $"My Tabbed Page - Tab [{SelectedTab + 1}]";

        this._unityContainer = unityContainer;
        _unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IMyTabbedPageSelectedTab>(this, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

    public void SetSelectedTab(int tabIndex)
    {
        SelectedTab = tabIndex;
    }
}
```

Can someone shed some light on what may be the problem?

Comment: Where do you register the container? Which container instance do you register? Anyway, injecting the container is so wrong, and using it in the view model is so wrong, too. Having a `SetSelectedTab` _and_ `SelectedTab.set` is also very confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I get that this problably isn't the best solution, it's a byproduct of choosing code from the web without understanding what it does. I've redone this feature implementing another solution and is working.